# How to visualize the intersection of 2 rectangles or more in a different color with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this demo code which generates colored rectangles with Matlplotlib. After several hours searching everywhere, I still do not understand how to visualize the intersection between 2 rectangles or more in a different color. Thank you very much.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

rect1 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((-675, -374),
                                    744, 412,
                                    color ='green')

rect2 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((-48, -454),
                                    116, 491,
                                    color ='blue')

rect3 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((-1009, -189),
                                    1074, 225,
                                    color ='yellow')

ax.add_patch(rect1)
ax.add_patch(rect2)
ax.add_patch(rect3)

plt.xlim([-1100, 1100])
plt.ylim([-1100, 1100])

plt.show()
```

[Actual Plot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aQ4q.png)

Comment: Maybe you can use alpha? E.g. `Rectangle(..., color=..., alpha=0.6)`

Comment: Opacity will be applied on each rectangle's space while what I want is to distinguish intersection only. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rectangles aren't rotated, the intersection can be calculated via maximum of the left sides, the minimum of the right sides (and similar for top and bottom).

For more complicated intersections, [Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) is an alternative.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

def intersect_rectangles(rect1_xywh, rect2_xywh):
    (x1, y1), w1, h1 = rect1_xywh
    (x2, y2), w2, h2 = rect2_xywh
    x = max(x1, x2)
    y = max(y1, y2)
    w = min(x1 + w1, x2 + w2) - x
    h = min(y1 + h1, y2 + h2) - y
    w = w if w > 0 else 0
    h = h if h > 0 else 0
    return ((x, y), w, h)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

rect1_xywh = ((-675, -374), 744, 412)
rect2_xywh = ((-48, -454), 116, 491)
rect3_xywh = ((-1009, -189), 1074, 225)

rect1 = Rectangle(*rect1_xywh, color='green')
rect2 = Rectangle(*rect2_xywh, color='blue')
rect3 = Rectangle(*rect3_xywh, color='yellow')

ax.add_patch(rect1)
ax.add_patch(rect2)
ax.add_patch(rect3)

intersect12_xywh = intersect_rectangles(rect1_xywh, rect2_xywh)
intersect13_xywh = intersect_rectangles(rect1_xywh, rect3_xywh)
intersect23_xywh = intersect_rectangles(rect2_xywh, rect3_xywh)
intersect123_xywh = intersect_rectangles(intersect_rectangles(rect1_xywh, rect2_xywh), rect3_xywh)

intersect12 = Rectangle(*intersect12_xywh, color='turquoise')
intersect13 = Rectangle(*intersect13_xywh, color='orange')
intersect23 = Rectangle(*intersect23_xywh, color='purple')
intersect123 = Rectangle(*intersect123_xywh, color='crimson')

ax.add_patch(intersect12)
ax.add_patch(intersect13)
ax.add_patch(intersect23)
ax.add_patch(intersect123)

ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image: intersection of rectangles]

Comment: thank you but it still not showing intersection with different color. To achieve this, I am open to different python library and not restricted to Matplotlib.

Comment: Oh sorry I was on mobile and didn't recognized it. It was not my intention to receive free snippet or code. I really was overwhelmed how to achieve this. I spent 3 days searching and found nothing. You saved me. Thank you very much!